# Can I still get a shiny 2nd gen starter in oras

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I saved and accidentally locked myself in the house with a full party while trying to soft reset for gen 2 starters in oras. I just want to know if I can still get one since I have to check the pc to know if I got a shiny.

Answer (score 1):

All the details of a Pokemon are finalized when you received the Pokemon, so if you have yet to pick the Johto starter Pokemon, you are still good to soft reset.